# Geopandas overlay issue

Tags: overlay, geopandas

I am trying to get an overlay (intersection) of two collections of polygons
in geopandas:

`splits = gp.overlay(nhds, cts, how='intersection')`

but result is very weired (see the picture below).

I opened an issue on geopandas github, but wondered if someone saw similar behavior or can detect what is going on (I am inclined to blame spatial index) here from the image

[image]

Comment: This is being discussed in https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/677

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issie disappeared after
- rebooting geopandas and installing "clean" gdal version
- replacing geojson census_tract dataset with the shapefile - probably, there was an issue with the geometry